# What extensions became part of the core in OpenGL ES 3.2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-extensions

With the introduction of Open GL ES 3.2 several extensions became part of the core API.

Several of these extensions are part of the Android Extension Pack and, according to the GLES 3.2 specification, out of all the AEP extensions, only sGRB decode did not make the cut.

What are the extensions that made it into the latest version of OpenGL ES 3.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the list of extensions that are part of the core specification of OpenGL ES 3.2

- KHR_debug
- KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr
- KHR_blend_equation_advanced
- OES_sample_shading
- OES_sample_variables
- OES_shader_image_atomic
- OES_shader_multisample_interpolation
- OES_texture_stencil8
- OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array
- {EXT, OES}_copy_image
- {EXT, OES}_draw_buffers_indexed
- {EXT, OES}_geometry_shader
- {EXT, OES}_gpu_shader5
- {EXT, OES}_primitive_bounding_box
- {EXT, OES}_shader_io_blocks
- {EXT, OES}_tessellation_shader
- {EXT, OES}_texture_border_clamp
- {EXT, OES}_texture_buffer
- {EXT, OES}_texture_cube_map_array
- OES_draw_elements_base_vertex
- EXT_color_buffer_float
- KHR_robustness

Sources:

- [Android Extension Pack specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/ANDROID/ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a.txt)
- [NVIDIA Developers](https://developer.nvidia.com/opengl-driver)
- [OpenGL ES 3.2 Spec (Section F.1)](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/#specs32)